Pairwise tests for OLS model with multiple predictors
I would like to ask for help with the following problem:
My LR model ols(formula="Income~ Major + Experience"), where Major is a categorical predictor and Experience is a scale predictor.
Both predictors are significant and I would like to know at what levels the categorical predictors differ.
The problem is that classic Python post hoc tests do not inherently adjust for the contributions of other predictors and are based solely on the predictor being examined.
I have only found statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.t_test_pairwise, but I am not sure how it works in the presence of interactions.
Could anyone tell me what is the best approach to pairwise testing in OLS models with multiple predictors (with and without interactions)?
Thanks a lot

I wonder whether we are interpreting your question as you intended.  In particular, I can't truly figure out what you mean by "at what levels the categorical predictors differ."  (What form of difference do you mean and why do you refer to plural "predictors" when only one categorical predictor occurs in your model?) Would you mind elaborating on that or providing a simple example?

If you have a simple model without interactions, as in your example, the association between Income and Major is independent of the value of Experience. You thus don't need to "adjust for the contributions of other predictors." Choose some particular value of Experience if necessary (the software might make some default choice like the mean Experience) and then do your pairwise comparisons among levels of Major.
Otherwise you need the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates to do this. That should be available somewhere in the object returned by the model fit. (I'm not sure where in this case, as I'm not fluent in Python.)
Once you have that, you can evaluate the standard error of any combination of coefficients and predictor values you want, to see for example whether the difference between two scenarios is significantly different from 0. You use the formula for the variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables, where the weights are the (differences in) predictor values and the correlated variables are the coefficient estimates with their (co)variances. That can be done with any set of regression coefficients, including those for interaction terms. With an interaction, recognize that the pairwise comparisons will depend on the value of the interacting predictor variable.
That process provides the standard error of the estimated difference in outcome between the 2 scenarios. In ordinary least squares you use the product of that times the t-statistic at the desired level of confidence to evaluate statistical significance. You then need to correct for the multiple comparisons you perform.
I don't know what tools Python provides to simplify that task. In R, the emmeans package can do this for a wide variety of model types. From what I've seen on this site, I suspect that R is much more user-friendly for this type of work.

+1. But I suspect the OP might have been trying to ask something different, although I'm unsure what.  Maybe it concerns comparing slopes associated with different design matrix columns that dummy-encode the categorical factor?

@whuber I took the OP to be asking about pairwise differences among multiple levels of a single categorical predictor, interpreting it to mean: "I would like to know which levels of the categorical predictor differ from each other in terms of outcome." If there's a clarification otherwise, I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Hi, thanks to both of you. "Predictors" was a typo, I meant the categorical predictor, as Edm correctly guessed. I am interested in the difference between main effects of levels of this categorical predictor.
